# Re-usable key binding in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, putty

I suspect this has previously been asked somewhere, but I cannot find it.

Anyway, I have set up a key-binding so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> opens Putty in Windows7. so far so good.

However, this is only a single use binding. If I re-use<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> it simply pops up the Putty session I am already using. Since I want many Putty session this is a bit useless.

Can I set this keyboard binding to create more and more new Putty session to mimic the behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> in Ubuntu?